# "canvas.clearRect is not a function" when I clear the canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle in a HTML5 canvas and move it around.

I wrote this Javascript code:

```js
var a = 0;
      function draw() {
        var c = document.getElementById("game");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(45+a, 45, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        a++;
      }
      var t=setInterval(draw,1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

When I try to execute it, I get this error in the console:

*TypeError: canvas.clearRect is not a function*

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: s/canvas/context, you action on the context, not the canvas itself. The error indicates the code shown is not the code you're running as well. otherwise it would complain about `ctx.clearRect` not `canvas.clearRect`

Comment: `canvas ` is undefined right ?

Comment: Please put `var c = document.getElementById("game");`& the `var ctx = c.getContext("2d");` outside the function, as global variables. Also you may use `c.width, c.height` in your function instead of `canvas.width, canvas.height`

Answer (score 4):

In `clearRect` method, `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` will throw an error as `canvas` is *undefined*. You should be passing valid object.

```js
var a = 0;

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(45 + a, 45, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  a++;
}
var t = setInterval(draw, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is correct, but that would throw a completely different error than what has been reported by OP.

Comment: @rlemon - I executed his code instead of focusing on the error he mentioned.

Comment: fair enough, but I'd still like to see the actual code that produced that error. The error pointed out here might not even exist in that case.   
Still, you are correct. I don't want to sound combative about that, just that OP needs to do a bit more work before we can reasonably answer them.

Comment: Ok, now I see my error, thank you :)
By the way, what kind of error i will get with Rayon solution?

Comment: none, his solution is working code. :) your question created confusion because the error message you said you were getting was not possible given the code you shared.